# Where are the tombs of Jesus' original 12 Apostles

Tags: history, apostles

I would like a list of the twelve Apostles, correlated with their most probable burial location. I understand that many reliquaries containing parts of their bodies were distributed throughout Christendom, but if there is a "primary" burial location for each, I would like to see it.

Additionally, I would like to know the date associated with each burial location, and I understand that it may have been established well after the death of the Apostles in question. I'm not seeking to see if each site is in fact "the" actual location, so much as to understand where I could visit any particular shrine.

(1) Is there any information on the possible tombs, i.e. not the cenotaphs if any, of the Apostles of Jesus Christ? I have seen *and* visited other tombs of other christian historical figures. 
2) how far does this go in time? That is, which known tomb would be the *oldest*?

Comment: I have no idea why this question has 2 close votes, both of which are "too broad". This question sounds like a historical question and demands a historical answer. The historical answer may be that "we don't know yet" or that "we have evidence of this guy's tomb".

Comment: @bruisedreed But the question asks for the original 12 apostles. All but Judas became saints.

Comment: I didn't VTC, but wouldn't this be better in history.se?

Comment: @TheFreemason I don't think so. For the most part this will have traditional, rather than strictly historical, answers. It's also of interest to those studying Christianity and not as much to those studying history as a discipline.

Comment: @DoubleU I think "too broad" comes in because there are 12 of them, and the voters are thinking asking about one at a time is better. I don't agree with that thinking, however. I doubt there's much to say about each; it's just a matter of compiling all the available material.

Comment: I think focusing on the original 12 only is probably not too broad.

Comment: Just an FYI, if this question gets closed, I plan on voting to reopen. This is a great question, as Mr. Bultitude's answer shows!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got most of this information by perusing Wikipedia.

- Simon Peter (brother of Andrew) - traditionally said to be [buried in Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter's_tomb), under [St. Peter's Basilica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter%27s_Basilica). The tomb dates between 130 and 300.
- James (son of Zebedee and older brother of John) also called "James the Greater" - as the patron saint of Spain, he is said to have been buried in [Santiago de Compostela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_de_Compostela) after his remains were carried there when he was beheaded in Jerusalem. The pilgrimage site originated in the 9th century.
- John (son of Zebedee and brother of James) - traditionally said to have been [buried in Ephesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_St._John). The basilica has been there since the 6th century, but his remains are said to have not been found.
- Andrew (brother of Simon Peter) - traditionally said to have been [buried in Patras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Andrew_of_Patras), Greece. In 357 the relics were transferred to Constantinople. In 867 the skull was sent back to Patras, and in 1208 those that remained in Constantinope were sent to [Amalfi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalfi), Italy. In 1908 all relics were returned to Patras.
- Philip of Bethsaida - traditions say he was martyred in [Hierapolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierapolis), and archaeologists claim to have [found his tomb](http://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-sites-places/biblical-archaeology-sites/tomb-of-apostle-philip-found/) in 2011. [Santi Apostoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santi_Apostoli,_Rome) is said to contain his remains now (having been transferred from the tomb to [Constantinople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople) and then there before the tomb was discovered). It's unclear to me when the remains are supposed to have been transferred there.
- Thomas (Didymus) - there are a number of places associated with his martyrdom and burial, but the most commonly accepted seem to be a martyrdom on [St. Thomas' Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Thomas_Mount) in India and burial nearby where [San Thome Basilica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Thome_Basilica) was later erected. It's unclear when exactly the site became associated with him, but it appears to have been 1523 at the latest.
- Bartholomew (Nathaniel) - said to have been martyred in [Albanopolis, Armenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanopolis,_Armenia) with his remains being shuffled around for a while later until they came to rest in the [Basilica of St. Bartholomew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Bartolomeo_all'Isola) in Rome in 1180.
- Matthew (Levi son of Alphaeus) of Capernaum - said to be [buried in Salerno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salerno_Cathedral), Italy, where a cathedral was built in 1076.
- James (son of Alphaeus) also called "James the Lesser" - [Hippolytus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolytus_of_Rome) said he was stoned to death in Jerusalem, but [Nikephoros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikephoros_Kallistos_Xanthopoulos) said he was crucified in Ostrakine, Egypt. His relics are in [Santi Apostoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santi_Apostoli,_Rome) with Philip. As with Philip, it's unclear to me when the site became associated with him.
- Simon the Zealot - relics are in [St. Peter's Basilica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter%27s_Basilica) in the same complex as Peter (so dated between 130 and 300)
- Judas Thaddaeus (Lebbaeus), called "Jude of James" (brother or son of someone named James, possibly one of the Jameses in this list) - relics are in [St. Peter's Basilica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter%27s_Basilica) in the same complex as Peter (so dated between 130 and 300)
- Judas Iscariot - died in [Akeldama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akeldama) and presumably still there, but nobody has been terribly interested in venerating the tomb of a traitor
- Matthias - the Greeks claim he's [buried in Gonio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonio), Georgia but Catholics have had his relics in [St. Matthew's Abbey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Matthias) in Trier, Germany since 1148

Comment: If I recall correctly, the tradition about Peter is that he was originally buried somewhere else, but was exhumed sometime later and placed under the Basilica in Rome.

Comment: @fredsbend [Doesn't appear so.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter#Burial_and_relics)

Comment: A small inquiry, I'm weak in counting... I think there are 13 or 14 people in your list... 12 expected.. <ERROR>

Comment: @servantofWiser There are indeed 13. When Judas betrayed Jesus and killed himself, the apostles appointed Matthias to take his place. You can read of Judas's betrayal and death in [Matthew 26-27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26-27) and [Acts 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+1&version=NET).

Comment: I don't understand when Jesus (pbuh) himself said "These are the names of the twelve apostles" [Mat 10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+10&version=VOICE) ...

Comment: @servantofWiser Jesus was generous to his apostles, [giving them authority to do many things.](http://timedisplaced.blogspot.com/2015/04/jesus-to-apostles-youre-alright-in-my.html) Why shouldn't choosing a replacement for one of their disgraced members be among those powers? Not only that, but they [asked Jesus who it should be](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+1:23-26). If you have further comments, please put them on the blog post I linked, or in the [Polemics and Apologetics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21614/polemics-and-apologetics) chatroom.

Comment: Which of the James' in this list do protestants reckon was Jesus' brother?

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle I'm not aware of any group, Protestant or otherwise, that believes Jesus' brother/relative James was one of the Twelve.

Comment: really! weird, I've been going along for most of my time as a Christian believing that the author of the book of James was both an apostle and Jesus' relative.

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle I believe he is considered an apostle in a broader sense, like Paul, Barnabas, Silas, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude right. Just to get things perfectly clear: which of the James' in the list in your answer wrote the epistle of James? (Or was it the "Jesus' brother/psuedoapostle" James who wrote it?)

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle That's disputed, but usually the brother of Jesus is assumed.